# Looking for most efficient way to write this INSERT query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert, performance

**Looking for most efficient way to write this INSERT query (and least code):**

```
INSERT INTO [exportnote] (
    [versionnumber],
    [createdate],
    [LabAccessioningNumber],
    [Text],
    [exporttestresultreportid]
) 
SELECT 
    1,
    GETDATE(),
    @lan,
    notetemp.notetext,
    @new_exporttestresultreportid
FROM 
(
    SELECT dbo.[note].notetext
    FROM dbo.[note] 
    WHERE  
        [note].notetypeid IN (15,17) -- SAMPLE NOTES  possibly 5,3
        AND [note].noteobjectid = @sampleid -- dbo.[sample].sampleid
        AND [note].active = 1 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        dbo.[note].notetext
    FROM 
        dbo.[note]
    WHERE 
        [note].notetypeid IN (11) -- CLIENT NOTES
        AND [note].noteobjectid = @clientid -- dbo.[client].clientid
        AND [note].active = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        dbo.[note].notetext
    FROM 
        dbo.[note]
    WHERE 
        [note].notetypeid IN (2,7) -- TEST NOTES
        AND [note].noteobjectid = @testid -- dbo.[test].testid
        AND dbo.[note].active = 1
) AS notetemp
```

Comment: You know, with these "requirements", I will have to post my hourly rate here...

Comment: Is there a problem with what you have (i.e. is it slow)?

Comment: Adrian, you're getting paid reputation points.  haha!  ...Paddy - I thought I could combine the 3 queries into 1 query.  I don't have to .. it works fine.  If I don't hear back from anyone by tomorrow, I'll just delete this question.

Comment: Don't do that. Read the FAQ. If you don't get an answer, **improve your question**. This is why I teased you about the requirements. There's too little info for an effective answer. Rule of thumb: want a good answer? Post a good question!

Comment: is wording the subject to "least code" a better way to phrase it?

Comment: "Most concise yet maintainable" might be better

Comment: Most efficient and least code are often at odds. More efficient should trump in a database. Check out the Execution plan of the orginal and the shorter version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This? OR and UNION *on the same table* are often interchangeable:

```
INSERT ...
SELECT
    1,
    GETDATE(),
    @lan,
    n.notetext,
    @new_exporttestresultreportid
FROM dbo.[note] n
WHERE  
    n.active = 1 
    AND
    (
       (n.notetypeid IN (15,17) AND n.noteobjectid = @sampleid)
        OR
       (n.notetypeid IN (2,7) AND n.noteobjectid = @testid)
        OR
       (n.notetypeid IN (11) AND n.noteobjectid = @clientid)
    )
```

Comment: I suggest using parentheses around the grouped clauses you want evaluated together when mixing OR and AND.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: I find it cluttered usually. AND vs OR precedence is pretty much standard...

Answer (score 2):

You could merge the 3 selects into 1:

```
SELECT dbo.[note].notetext    
 FROM dbo.[note]      
WHERE  [note].active = 1         
 AND  ( 
           ( [note].notetypeid IN (15,17)       
              AND [note].noteobjectid = @sampleid )
       OR (  [note].notetypeid IN (11) 
              AND [note].noteobjectid = @clientid )
       OR (  [note].notetypeid IN (2,7)        
             AND [note].noteobjectid = @testid )
      )
```